# How to understand the proof of $\mathbb{E}[X+Y] = \mathbb{E}[X] + \mathbb{E}[Y]$ with continuous random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$I'm studying Expectation, according to the book, for two continuous random variables, we have

$$\E(X+Y)=\E(X) + \E(Y)$$

The proof is as follows.

$$\E[X+Y] = \int^∞_{-∞}\int^∞_{-∞}(x+y)f(x,y)dxdy$$
$$= \int^∞_{-∞}\int^∞_{-∞}xf(x,y)dydx + \int^∞_{-∞}\int^∞_{-∞}yf(x,y)dxdy\tag1$$
$$= \int^∞_{-∞}xf_X(x)dx + \int^∞_{-∞}yf_Y(y)dy\tag2$$
$$= \E[X] + \E[Y]$$

How can we get (2) from (1)? More specifically, why $\int^∞_{-∞}f(x,y)dy=f_X(x)$?

Comment: $f_X(x)$ is the *marginal* probability density function (same for $Y$)...it is obtained by integrating the joint pdf with respect to the other variable. See https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/107

Comment: "why $\int^∞_{-∞}f(x,y)dy=f_X(x)$?" Because, for every Borel set $A$, $$P(X\in A)=P((X,Y)\in A\times\mathbb R)=\iint_{A\times\mathbb R}f(x,y)dxdy=\int_A\left(\int_\mathbb Rf(x,y)dy\right)dx$$

Comment: You can think of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)dy$ as integrating all $y'$s out - leaving you with just the marginal distribution of $X$, $f_{X}(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int^∞_{-∞}\int^∞_{-∞}xf_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx = \int^∞_{-∞}x \left[\int^∞_{-∞}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy \right]dx$$
$$= \int^∞_{-∞}x[f_X(x)]dx \tag{*}$$

---

We are given by definition that the marginal pdf of $X$ is

$$f_X(x) = \int^∞_{-∞}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy$$

How do we know that this is also the pdf of $X$ given by $p_X(x)$? It is the pdf of $X$ iff

$$\int^x_{-∞} f_X(t) dt$$

or

$$\int^x_{-∞}\int^∞_{-∞}f_{X,Y}(t,y)dydt$$

is the cdf of $X$ which is given by $$P(X \le x) = \int^x_{-∞} p_X(t) dt$$

So I guess we have to show that for all $x$,

$$\int^x_{-∞}\int^∞_{-∞}f_{X,Y}(t,y)dydt$$ has all the properties of  $$\int^x_{-∞} p_X(t) dt$$?

If so, these would be nondecreasing, approaching 1 as $x \to \infty$, approaching 0 as $x \to -\infty$ etc

Comment: Sorry if this is kind of stupid, but I just cannot wrap my head around. I know that $f_X(x)$ is the probability density function of $X$, and $f(x,y)$ is the joint probability density function of $x$ and $y$. I can see that $\int_{-∞}^∞f(x,y)dy$ will give me a function only containing $x$, something like $f(x)$. But how can I be sure that **this** $f(x)$ I mentioned is the probability density function of $x$? I guess it is, but I cannot find a concrete way to prove that.

Comment: @Searene Very good question. I'm coming up with an answer now

Comment: @Searene Edited. I have a feeling I will soon be downvoted and corrected though. There may be some advanced probability concept of the uniqueness of pdfs. Idk

Comment: "We are given by definition that the marginal pdf of $X$ is $f_X(x) = \int^∞_{-∞}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy$" No we are not given this by definition, actually we are asked why this holds (hence assuming it holds is a sure way to get some offtopic considerations).

Comment: @Did Depends on text? [p. 15](http://www.colorado.edu/economics/morey/7818/jointdensity/jointdensity.pdf)

Comment: No, not "depends on text". **Read the question**.